# Heatmap colorbars accumulating in Matplotlib/Seaborn figures

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn, heatmap, colorbar

I have a list of data frames, and I want to make heatmaps of every data frame in the list. The first heatmap comes out perfectly, but the second one has two colorbars, one much larger than the other, which distorts the figure. The third has THREE colorbars, the last one being even larger, and this continues for as many heatmaps as I make.

This seems like a bug to me, as I have no idea why it's happening. Each heatmap should be stored as a separate element in the list of heatmaps, and even if I plot them individually, instead of using a loop or list comprehension, I get the same problem.

Here is my code:

```
# Set the seaborn font size.
sns.set(font_scale=0.5)
# Ensure that labels are not cut off. 
plt.gcf().subplots_adjust(bottom=0.18)
plt.gcf().subplots_adjust(right=.3)

black_yellow = sns.dark_palette("yellow",10)

heatmap_list = [sns.heatmap(df, cmap=black_yellow, xticklabels=True, yticklabels=True) for df in df_list]
[heatmap_list[x].figure.savefig(file_names_list[x]+'.pdf', format='pdf') for x in range(0,len(heatmap_list))]
```

Comment: I think you want to produce a separate figure per heatmap, right? A figure is produced by `plt.figure()`.

Comment: the figure in this case is produced by sns.heatmap(), which I believe is still a legitimate way to produce a figure. Anyway, the problem I am having is not that the figures aren't being produced, it's that the color bar is getting duplicated and enlarged each time the list comprehension goes through the loop. I can't see why that would be.

Comment: `sns.heatmap()` will produce a figure, if no previous figure is active. Else it will produce the heatmap in the active figure. But that is the cause for the multiple colorbars. Hence you would want to create a new figure per heatmap. That would be done via `plt.figure()`.

Comment: Well if I use plt.figure(), how will I indicate what type of figure I want? Anyway, I found the answer. I just have to clear the plot space between heatmaps.

Answer (score 0):

**sns.heatmap()** creates a problem while we are working in loop. To resolve this issue, the first iteration will be done individually and rest of the loop remains the same but we will add a parameter `cbar=False` to stop this recursion of colorbar in the loop portion.

```
# Set the seaborn font size.
sns.set(font_scale=0.5)
# Ensure that labels are not cut off. 
plt.gcf().subplots_adjust(bottom=0.18)
plt.gcf().subplots_adjust(right=.3)

black_yellow = sns.dark_palette("yellow", 10)
hm = sns.heatmap(df_list[0], cmap=black_yellow, xticklabels=True, yticklabels=True)
hm.figure.savefig(file_names_list[0]+'.pdf', format='pdf')
heatmap_list = [sns.heatmap(df_list[i], cmap=black_yellow, xticklabels=True, yticklabels=True, cbar=False) for i in range(1, len(df_list))]
[heatmap_list[x].figure.savefig(file_names_list[x+1]+'.pdf', format='pdf') for x in range(0, len(heatmap_list))]
```